# How search engines find the content duplication of a website

Tags: search-engine, duplicates

I would like to know how search engines find that a content in the website is a duplicate content?

And also how do they determine that it might be duplicated, do they use any specific technique or any tag line for it?

Please provide me suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how the big search engines do it, but one technique I've used is min hasing with n-grams of the content. We did this for a crawler where we were finding many broken sites that link to the same page with an infinite number of unique urls. We needed a quick way to detect similar pages out of a very large so that we could then apply more expensive duplicate content checks.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinHash

Edit: Here are some more links, including a paper from **Google**

http://knol.google.com/k/simple-simhashing#

http://infolab.stanford.edu/~manku/papers/07www-duplicates.pdf